# Buscando datas através de BETWEEN AND

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte situação, onde ao tentar consultar uma data até outra data utilizando **BETWEEN**, a data limite especificada não retorna, apenas "o dia anterior".

Existe algum contorno para resolver essa questão?

**Segue as datas gravadas no banco e o Select gerado:**

```
2016-04-12 16:07:03
2016-04-12 16:33:08
2016-04-14 10:47:33
2016-04-14 11:21:14

SELECT * FROM sales.logger where data BETWEEN "2016-04-12" AND "2016-04-14" ORDER BY data;
```

**Retorno**:

```
2016-04-12 16:07:03
2016-04-12 16:33:08
```

Comment: Ja tentou, where data >= "2016-04-12" and data <= "2016-04-14"

Comment: Já tentou aspa simples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema parece ser que você está tratando tipos `DATETIME` como `DATE`.

Tente:

```
SELECT * FROM sales.logger where data BETWEEN "2016-04-12 00:00:00" AND "2016-04-14 23:59:59" ORDER BY data;
```

Comment: Exelente, Resolveria meu problema, porem para casos como - where data BETWEEN "2016-04-12 10:00:00" AND "2016-04-14 10:00:00" , não me retornaria o dia 14 até as 10hrs, qual seria o paliativo?

Comment: Olá Matheus, não sei se entendi seu comentário. Se você quer todas as transações entre meia noite e 10 da manhã use:  `where data BETWEEN "2016-04-12 00:00:00" AND "2016-04-14 10:00:00"`

Comment: Olá Anthony, problema resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Vocês pode converter a data

Tente:

```
SELECT * FROM sales.logger where date(data) BETWEEN "14-04-2016" AND "14-04-2016" ORDER BY data;
```

Comment: Entrei só para votar, resolveu o problema de maneira fácil e rápida, mesmo 4 anos depois do post...

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver o problema, há duas formas de fazer usando `BETWEEN`, quando se usa `datetime`:

```
SELECT * FROM sales.logger where DATE_FORMAT(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
BETWEEN '2016-04-12' AND '2016-04-14' ORDER BY data;
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM sales.logger where data
BETWEEN '2016-04-12 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-14 00:00:00' ORDER BY data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução estável para seleção de dados entre duas datas consiste em não usar a data final, mas sim o *dia seguinte da data final*. Quando no seu sistema tiver um filtro de duas datas, obtém o dia seguinte da data maior e no banco:

```
SELECT * FROM sales.logger where data >= "2016-04-12" AND data < "2016-04-15";
```

Repare que a data menor é comparada com maior igual, mas a data final é comparada só com menor.

Esse código funciona:

- Com campos data (YYYY-MM-DD)
- Com campos data e hora (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)
- Com campos data, hora e fração de qualquer tamanho

  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.F
  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FF
  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFF
  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFF
  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFF
  - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFFFFFF
  - ... e assim por diante

Parece uma solução feia, mas gera código que funciona sempre, mas principalmente quando se está utilizando ferramentas de geração de código, onde pode não haver controle de que precisão do campo data está sendo utilizada (data, timestamp, timestamp com fração N).