# MySQL selecionar dados por período

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou tentando selecionar dados que comecem em uma data e termine em outra, estou fazendo desta forma:

```
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE feita_em >= '2019-10-10' AND feita_em <= '2019-10-11'
```

E este é o resultado:

[image: Resultado da query]

Porém eu possuo dados no dia 11, mas eles não estão sendo mostrados na query, apenas o dia 10, e eu preciso desses dados para produzir meus relatórios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O fator é que você grava `datetime` e faz comparação com `date` uma solução é utilizar a função `date()` do banco da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE date(feita_em) >= '2019-10-10' 
                       AND date(feita_em) <= '2019-10-11'
```

isso já vai resolver porque independente de hora que a data tem ele só vai considerar a data.

Uma outra forma seria adequar o hora nessa comparação onde a data inicial começa a `00:00:00` horas e a data final termina das `23:59:59` sendo ai desnecessário a conversão da data armazenada no banco, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE feita_em >= '2019-10-10 00:00:00' 
                       AND feita_em <= '2019-10-11 23:59:59'
```

Com [BETWEEN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123557/buscando-datas-atrav%C3%A9s-de-between-and) e o ajuste que já foi explicado:

```
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE date(feita_em) BETWEEN '2019-10-10' AND '2019-10-11' // ou
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE feita_em BETWEEN '2019-10-10 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-11 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Pergunta nada a ver, nesta situacao qual seria a mais eficaz ?

Comment: @ScrapBench a sua pergunta é boa sim, teria que analisar as duas `SQL` uma passa pela conversão a outra não vai depender do cenário. Sinceridade tem que verificar o plano de execução das duas, para poucas informações acho eu (achismo, sem teste) que não tem diferenças significativas

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema vem de tratares datetimes como dates tenta isto

```
SELECT * FROM vendas  WHERE feita_em BETWEEN '2019-10-10' AND '2019-10-11';
```

Comment: erro de sintaxe

Comment: sryja alterei esqueci de tirar o `=>`

Comment: Mesmo resultado

Comment: Erro Sintaxico? ou sem as compras do dia 11 ?